# Store NSTimeZone in Core Data

Tags: core-data, ios7, nstimezone

I tried to save `NSTimeZone` as transformable type, but it doesn't work seems due to it conforms to `NSSecureCoding`.

Is it any other alternatives?

Comment: Using transformable *should* just work. `NSSecureCoding` inherits from `NSCoding`, and any object that conforms to `NSCoding` works with transformable attributes. I don't know what the problem is without seeing code, but the approach you describe is actually the correct approach to the problem.

Comment: @TomHarrington I just checked and yes, that was my fail. It works as transformable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the TimeZone has a defined `name`, you can store that as a string.  It may not have a name if you manually constructed the timeZone based off a GMT offset.

... So you could store the GMT offset if you wanted, but then you would lose any of the DST information associated with a named timezone.

Probably the best way is to store the `data`.  That *should* contain the information necessary to reconstruct the appropriate `NSTimeZone` instance.

Comment: ```[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timeZoneName data:timeZoneData]``` To fully reconstruct ```NSTimeZone``` we need to store both name and data.